# Screen rendering twice

Tags: react-native

In my react-native application i want to show a screen based on a state.

**Login.js**

```
export default class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            accessTokenExists: false
        }
    }

     accessvalid = () => {
          tokenStorage.getToken('accesstoken')
        .then(res => {
             fetchTokens.validAccessToken(res)
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({accessTokenExists: true});
                console.log('Existing Accesstoken');
            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            this.setState({accessTokenExists: false});
            console.log('Not Existing AccesToken');
        })    
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        this.accessvalid();
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        SplashScreen.hide();


    }

    render() {
        if(this.state.accessTokenExists){
            return(<Fingerprint navigation={this.props.navigation}/>)
        } else {
            return(<Password navigation={this.props.navigation}/>)
        }

    }
}
```

when the state **accesTokenExists** is **true** react renders first the other screen for a split second and then re-rendering the right screen.

Is this because the API calls i make before i changed the state in the **accesvalid** method.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request is asynchronous. When you make this request in ComponentWillMount it fires off the request and the component continues to render. Since the default state of this is false, `<Password navigation={this.props.navigation}/>` will render.

When the return comes back, if successful, the other component will mount. You want to handle the condition of "Requesting" as a state your component could be in to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it is because you set it to false in the constructor, and it takes time until ComponentWillMount sets it to true. A way to handle this may be by rendering a loading nessage until finishing to check whether accessTokenExists, using another state variable that will indicate whether loading is done or not. I assume, btw, that you know that componentWillMount is deprecated.